# SQLite Arraylist crashing android activity

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm having a problem with android and sqlite. When I receive data in the Arraylist the application crashes.

The DbHelper code is as follows:

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllAccelerometerRegists() {
    ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from acelerometer;", null );
    res.moveToFirst();

    while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
        array_list.add(res.getString(1));
        res.moveToNext();
    }

    return array_list;
}
```

The activity code is as follows:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_data);

    mydb = new DbHelper(this);

    ArrayList array_list = mydb.getAllAccelerometerRegists();


}
```

the dbhelper class is as follows:

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sportsmove.db";

public static final String TABLE_ACCELEROMETER_NAME = "acelerometer";
public static final String TABLE_GYROSCOPE_NAME = "gyroscope";
public static final String TABLE_ORIENTATION_NAME = "orientation";


private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String ID = "_id";
public static final String X = "x";
public static final String ACCELEROMETERX = "x";
public static final String GYROSCOPEX = "x";
public static final String ORIENTATIONX = "x";
public static final String Y = "y";
public static final String ACCELEROMETERY = "y";
public static final String GYROSCOPEY = "y";
public static final String ORIENTATIONY = "y";
public static final String Z = "z";
public static final String ACCELEROMETERZ = "z";
public static final String GYROSCOPEZ = "z";
public static final String ORIENTATIONZ = "z";
public static final String W = "w";
public static final String ORIENTATIONW = "w";
public static final String TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create database " + DATABASE_NAME + ";";

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_ACCELEROMETER = "create table "
        + TABLE_ACCELEROMETER_NAME + "( " + ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + ACCELEROMETERX
        + " int, " + ACCELEROMETERY + " int, "
        + ACCELEROMETERZ+" int, " + TIMESTAMP + "int);";

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_GYROSCOPE = "create table "
        + TABLE_GYROSCOPE_NAME + "( " + ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + GYROSCOPEX
        + " int, " + GYROSCOPEY + " int, "
        + GYROSCOPEZ+" int, " + TIMESTAMP + "int);";

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_ORIENTATION = "create table "
        + TABLE_ORIENTATION_NAME + "( " + ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + ORIENTATIONX
        + " int, " + ORIENTATIONY + " int, "
        + ORIENTATIONZ +" int, "+ ORIENTATIONW +" int, " + TIMESTAMP + "int);";

public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_ACCELEROMETER);
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_GYROSCOPE);
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_ORIENTATION);

    insertData(db);
}

public void insertData(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("insert into " + DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_ACCELEROMETER + "values(0,0,0,0,0)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(DbHelper.class.getName(),
            "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ACCELEROMETER_NAME);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_GYROSCOPE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ORIENTATION_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public ArrayList<String> getAllAccelerometerRegists() {
    ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();


    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from "+TABLE_ACCELEROMETER_NAME+";", null );
    res.moveToFirst();

    while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
        array_list.add(res.getString(1));
        res.moveToNext();
    }

    return array_list;
}

public boolean isTableExists(SQLiteDatabase db, String tableName) {
    if (tableName == null || db == null || !db.isOpen())
    {
        return false;
    }
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "+TABLE_ACCELEROMETER_NAME+"WHERE", new String[] {"table", tableName});
    if (!cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        return false;
    }
    int count = cursor.getInt(0);
    cursor.close();
    return count > 0;
}

public boolean insertAccelerometerRegister (String x, String y, String z, String timestamp,String username, String moveName)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("x", x);
    contentValues.put("y", y);
    contentValues.put("z", z);
    contentValues.put("timestamp", timestamp);
    contentValues.put("username", username);
    contentValues.put("moveName", moveName);
    db.insert(TABLE_ACCELEROMETER_NAME, null, contentValues);
    return true;
 }
}
```

the logcat error is as follows:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld, PID: 11058
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld/com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld.ViewData}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "database": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create database sportsmove.db;
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2344)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "database": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create database sportsmove.db;
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:901)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:512)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
    at database.DbHelper.onCreate(DbHelper.java:66)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
    at database.DbHelper.getAllAccelerometerRegists(DbHelper.java:93)
    at com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld.ViewData.onCreate(ViewData.java:26)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5976)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Comment: show the logcat of your error

Comment: please add some logs from logcat. Its the best place to find/trace your problem.

Comment: Process: com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld, PID: 11058
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld/com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld.ViewData}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "database": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create database sportsmove.db;
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "database": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create database sportsmove.db;

Comment: add log info in your question not as comment.

Comment: add your class DbHelper.java:

Comment: As per my analysis the problem exist in Data base creation. Could you please share the DBHelper please??

Answer (score 1):

Main reason is `DATABASE_CREATE = "create database " + DATABASE_NAME + ";";` 
when you execute it to create the database. Create database query is not supported by SQLite3. So syntax error occurs. Remove following line `db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);`

To create database this line is enough  `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);`
in constructor.

I think it helps you.

Comment: Still crashes.
Don't I need to create the database before query it?

Comment: Yes. database already created by SQLiteOpenHelper with the information provided in constructor. You only create the table in onCreate method. Now, where crash occurs.

Comment: The crash occurs in the assignment "= mydb.getAllAccelerometerRegists();" if the second part is commented it doesn't crash.

Comment: What is second part . any crash info

Answer (score 0):

Follow this step.

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllAccelerometerRegists() {
    ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    String selectQuery = "Select * FROM " + "acelerometer" + " ORDER BY id";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (res.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            array_list.add(res.getString(1));
        } while (res.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return array_list;
}
```

this array declare as global.

```
ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The activity code change like :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_data);
    mydb = new DbHelper(this);
    new GetCategories().execute();
}
```

this class for fetching record from SQLite.

```
// fetch Data
private class GetCategories extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        // pDialog.setMessage("Loding...");
        // pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        // pDialog.show();
        //Log.e("Currency", "3");
        //Globle.dilaog_show(HomeActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        array_list = db.getAllAccount();
        // here for get comman route no
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void resul) {
        super.onPostExecute(resul);
        // if (pDialog.isShowing())
        // pDialog.dismiss();
        //Globle.dilaog_diamiss();
        // this for added pending & completed account

    }
}
```